# Minimum Amount for Opening a new Wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc, wallet, technical-details

With a Monero fork, I am curious if there is a way to set a Minimum Amount for Opening or Activating a new Wallet.
The idea is that people have to deposit a certain amount of coins into a wallet before being able to send coins or receive block rewards from mining.

Answer (score 0):

Google Gemini did a good job of answering this question:

It's theoretically possible to implement a minimum deposit requirement for mining rewards in a Monero fork, but it would come with significant challenges and trade-offs. Here's a breakdown:

**Challenges:**

- **Technical complexity:** Modifying the existing codebase to enforce a minimum deposit would require significant technical expertise and potential changes to other core functionalities.
- **Network centralization:** Restricting participation by imposing a minimum deposit could discourage smaller miners and lead to network centralization, a concern Monero actively avoids.
- **Unequal rewards:** Larger miners with bigger deposits would receive a disproportionate share of rewards, potentially harming the network's fairness and decentralization.
- **Market manipulation:** It could be open to manipulation by wealthy individuals or groups attempting to exert control over the network.
- **Enforcement mechanisms:** Implementing and enforcing a minimum deposit consistently across all wallets and exchanges would be difficult.

**Potential benefits:**

- **Reducing spam and dust attacks:** High-value transactions are less susceptible to certain types of attacks, potentially improving network security.
- **Discouraging malicious activities:** Higher stakes might deter bad actors from using the network for nefarious purposes.

**Alternatives:**

Instead of a minimum deposit, consider exploring alternative solutions for the issues you might be trying to address, such as:

- **Increased block reward difficulty:** Adjusting the block reward difficulty over time can naturally discourage low-value mining without hindering smaller participants.
- **Proof-of-stake consensus:** Switching to a Proof-of-Stake consensus mechanism eliminates mining entirely, potentially addressing concerns about energy consumption and centralization.
- **Community moderation:** Fostering a strong community governance system can help identify and address malicious activities without imposing barriers to entry.

**Final Thoughts:**

While theoretically possible, a minimum deposit requirement for mining rewards in a Monero fork presents significant challenges and risks to the network's core principles of decentralization and fairness. Carefully consider the trade-offs and explore alternative solutions before implementing such a change.